# Writing large (>20KB) records with BigQueryIO

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

This wasn't clear from the documentation, but it looks like [BigQueryIO.write](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write) performs a streaming write, which in turn [limits the row size to <20KB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#quota)?

Is it possible to configure a non-streaming BigQuery write that enables support for the larger (1MB) row size? My DataFlow job is a batch job, not a streaming one, and BigQuery streaming is not necessary, and undesired in this case, since it restricts me from importing my data.

If not, what's the recommended workflow for importing large rows into BigQuery? I guess I can run the DataFlow ETL and write my data into text files using TextIO, but then I'd have to add a manual step outside of this pipeline to trigger a BQ import?

Answer (score 1):

Batch Datflow jobs don't stream data to BigQuery. The data is written to GCS and then we execute BigQuery import jobs to import the GCS files. So the streaming limits shouldn't apply.

Note the import job is executed by the service not by the workers which is why you don't see code for this in BigQueryIO.write.

Comment: Perhaps something else is tripping me up then.. When I try to run my import, I get the following error "{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}" -- not terribly helpful. On a whim, I've tried reducing the row size to <20KB, and it went through just fine - hmm? Any debugging tips?

Comment: Is it possible your record isn't valid and index: 0 is a reference to the column or field that is invalid?

Comment: I've had that error plenty of times before @igrigorik. Check your table schema (including types), then make sure your setting the correct fields and types on the output of your transformation e.g. ParDo